# One product under two cotegories

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to have the ability to have my products appear under multiple categories. I've been using `ManyToManyField` rather than `ForeignKey`. However I'm facing two problems:

When I go to a category detail page it's giving me an error when it iterates over the products. It's not getting the category slug but it is getting the product slug.

So when I navigate to `127.0.0.1:8000/products/cars/` I get:
`Reverse for 'model_detail_view' with arguments '('', 'blue-car')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<category_slug>[^/]+)/(?P<model_slug>[^/]+)/$']`

It should be having a slug of `127.0.0.1:8000/products/cars/blue-car`

Also my product model has a `BooleanField` that can feature the product on the homepage. How does if decide which category to use if it is under several categories?

**urls.py**

```
path("products/<str:category_slug>/", views.model_category_detail_view, name="model_category_detail_view"),
path("products/<str:category_slug>/<str:model_slug>/", views.model_detail_view, name="model_detail_view"),
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your urls.py file

Comment: I think what's happening is you have a link in your template, something like `{% url 'model_detail_view' 'blue-car' %}` when it needs to be `{% url 'model_detail_view' 'cars' 'blue-car' %}`.

Comment: @Ben I have `href="{% url 'main:model_detail_view' product.category.category_slug product.model_slug %}"`