# Iterate over all categories and all products each category

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to have a page where I loop over all my categories and all the products in each category.

Something like this:

```
Category 1:
product1
product2
product3

Category 2:
product1
product2
product3

Category 3:
product1
product2
product3
```

**views.py**

```
def model_categories_view(request):
    context = {
        "categories": ProductCategory.objects.all(),
        "models": ProductModel.objects.filter(???),
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/categories.html', context=context)
```

**categories.html**

```
{% for category in categories %}

    <h1>{{category.title}}</h1>
    {% for model  in models %}
        {{model.title}}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class ProductModel(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory)
    model_slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Models"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category_slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Product Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

How can I list all the models for the current category being iterated?

Comment: Can you please share the relevant models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Done

Comment: Likely `BoatCategory` is `ProductCategory` or vice-versa?

Comment: Yes I was trying to simplify my models

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the queryset of *related* products with `.productmodel_set`. You thus can thus write the template as:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
    {% for product in category.productmodel_set.all %}
        {{product.title}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To make sure that this is done efficiently, you can make use of [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to efficiently fetch all the related `Product`s for the given `ProductCategory`s:

```
def model_categories_view(request):
    context = {
        "categories": ProductCategory.objects.prefetch_related('productmodel')
    }
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name='main/categories.html',
        context=context
    )
```

> **Note**: normally models have *no* `Model` suffix, so you better rename <s>`ProductModel`</s> to `Product`.

Comment: I'm not sure where 'productmodel' comes from.

Comment: It is the `related_name_query` of the `ForeignKey` from the `ManyToMany` from `ProductModel` to `ProductCategory`. By default that is the name of the model in "snake_case".

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot find 'productmodel' on ProductCategory object, 'productmodel' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()` Perhaps this is being caused by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117918/one-product-under-two-cotegories?noredirect=1#comment106328867_60117918 I have been trying to solve this for awhile now..

Comment: @GTA.sprx: normally it should suggest relations. If you changed the names of your models, then of course these will be different.

Comment: It's not making any suggestions. I did everything as you showed and I'm still getting `AttributeError` `Cannot find 'productmodel' on ProductCategory object, 'productmodel' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`